# meaning of "realized" in "the full implications of Darwin’s revolution have yet to be widely realized."

Tags: comprehension

so I understand "realize" means "to become aware" or "comprehend", but I don't understand how this meaning fits into the sentence below.

"but the full implications of Darwin’s revolution have yet to be widely realized.

Does this mean the implicit meaning of Darwin's revolution/theory is yet to be fully UNDERSTOOD OR indications of Darwin's revolution'theory is yet to be SHOWN or MANIFEST ?

Thank you

Comment: have yet to have fully occurred.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be from the Selfish Gene by Richard Dawkins. The rest of the paragraph shows that "realized" here means "to understand" or "to appreciate the importance of":

"*Zoology is still a minority subject in universities, and even those who choose to study it often make their decision without appreciating its profound philosophical significance. Philosophy and the subjects known as 'humanities' are still taught as if Darwin had never lived.*"